# Canny Edge Detection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv

I am trying to implement a simple canny edge detector

in order to detect hair line, within a face tracker.

Before getting into the main loop of the facetracker

the following line that is commented out breaks my

program, giving this error message:

***Unhandled exception at 0x7709c41f in CVTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x004fb300..***

```
cout << "Hair Line Detection ...";

Mat GrayFace;

threshold( gray, GrayFace, 65, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

// Canny( GrayFace, GrayFace, 1, 150, 3, false );

threshold( GrayFace, GrayFace, 254, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY );

Mat EdgeDetection;

EdgeDetection = GrayFace;

cout << "Done!" << endl;
```

As a beginner, I have no clue why this line breaks the program.

Could someone kindly help me please?

Thank you,

Comment: I'm not sure whether the destination image is allowed to be the same as the source image for canny. Try `cv::Mat edges; Canny(GrayFace,edges,1,150,3,false);` instead. If that doesn't help, try an `imshow("GrayFace", GrayFace);` to see whether the input of your Canny is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, that was my first guess, but apparently it is allowed for these 2 to be the same, according to section 7 of this URL: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/canny_detector/canny_detector.html

Comment: can you provide sample images?

Comment: I cannot run it on an image yet, because this is embedded in a Face Tracker program. I now have to isolate this and see if I can run it separately...

Comment: can you just add an `imwrite("GrayFace.png",GrayFace);` before the `Canny`?

Comment: I just did that... It breaks: Unhandled exception at 0x7709c41f in CVTest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0035cfe4..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47177/discussion-between-joshua-and-micka)

Comment: @Micka, destination image is allowed to be same as source image for canny(: Done it many times myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just noticed that you have 2 threshold lines? What's the purpose of thresholding it twice at one go? (since you comment the canny line)

change your

```
cv::threshold( gray, GrayFace, 65, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
```

to

```
cv::threshold(gray, GrayFace, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
```

Let me know if it works now. Use `cv::imshow("Test GrayFace", GrayFace);` to display the new result.